# Stretching HTML page so the page can scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a website and an element on it, build using JQuery. I've entered the element but it seems it's bottom falls below my taskbar, and the web page doesn't notice it or something so I can't scroll. How can I force the HTML page to be 'longer' so the user can scroll?

Comment: You need to post code please.

Comment: Posting the code or giving a more succint description of the problem would help greatly.

Comment: Then I'd had to post a lot of stuff and photos to fill the element. You can see the element here: http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/examples/compact/ Imagine the text below that element would not be there. Even better, imagine that text above it so the photo gallery element would get 'pushed' down. Then you wouldn't be able to use the vertical slide bar because the website doesn't think the page is longer than you can see. I hope I made myself clear..

Comment: Make sure the CSS property `overflow` is not set to `hidden` (`overflow: hidden;`)

Comment: what browser? in the latest version of chrome it appears to scroll vertically just fine even when i use the web inspector to move the text above it and adjust the browser size to make it too small to fit everything

Comment: @DMTintner Seems like when using this in my own site, I can't scroll if there is nothing below..

Comment: @zsawyer I changed it (good call) but it didn't work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a height value into the body property of your css.

```
body{height:#;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `overflow` isn't `hidden`.

You have an element with that set `.cls-mobile-flash {overflow: hidden;}`

Maybe start with that, but we really need to see your code. Maybe do a JSfiddle

Answer (score 0):

How can I force the HTML page to be 'longer' so the user can scroll?

Just add `<br/>` at the bottom of your page like this :

```
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

PS. no need for the enclosing slash-brace at the end for html4, just use `<br>`

For your specific situation, you can check for 'overflow' and fixed height values.

Comment: This is probably a very bad idea.

Comment: @Terry I know it might lead to a very bad situation, but hey, i needed to laugh some pressure .. so why not suggesting the most unpredictable answer ? Instead of trying to gain some reputation writing jQuery of freakout javascript pretending to solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a `div` with a `GridView` in it and I wanted this div to be aoutoresizable, depending on the size of the window.

```
$(window).resize(function () { $("#<%=divGV.ClientID%>").height(getH()); });

    function getH() {
        var windowH = $(window).height();
        var topOfDiv = $("#<%=divGV.ClientID%>").offset().top;
        var variableH = 40; //40 to maintain the window height in order to not have the scrollbar in the browser
        var gvH = $("#cphMaster_gv").height() + variableH;
        var h = windowH - topOfDiv - variableH;
        if (h > gvH) { return gvH; }
        else { return h; }
    }
```

`divGV` is div, `cphMaster_gv` is my GridView.

Hope this gives you an idea...